# Android SQLite replace into not working

Tags: android, sqlite, replace

I have this sql query. But row with id=1 won't replace.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vergi_testler` (
  `_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `sual` text,
  `cavab1` text,
  `cavab2` text,
  `cavab3` text,
  `cavab4` text,
  `d_cavab` INTEGER,
  `verilib` INTEGER
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS  idx_neyse ON vergi_testler (_id);
REPLACE INTO `vergi_testler` VALUES (1, 'aaaa', 'aaa1', 'aaa1', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 2, 0);
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Your query works fine. Just tested with SQLite 3 and SQLiteStudio v2.1.4.

Comment: I know my query works fine. But for second time if I run 

REPLACE INTO `vergi_testler` VALUES (1, 'bbb', 'bbb1', 'bbb1', 'bbb3', 'bbb4', 2, 0);

it will not change row 1

Comment: It works here - sorry I cannot reproduce the error. Are there any error message?

Comment: no there is not any error message. Then, I think its related with android?

Comment: Well, you could try to access the database of your application using the `adb` tool and check that your queries are actually having the effect that you expect. The error might be located at different places - for instance in your data access layer or in the logic that prints the result of the query.

Comment: Try with `UPDATE` instead of `REPLACE INTO`

Comment: @shoerat That would require him to include the `SET` statement as well.

Comment: Works for mee, too. You probably are still using some old database (because of the `IF NOT EXISTS`).

Answer (score 0):

Supply column name `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO`vergi_testler`(_id,sual,cavab1,cavab2,cavab3,cavab4,d_cavab,verilib)` with table name in Query

**so try**

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS  idx_neyse ON vergi_testler (_id,sual,cavab1,cavab2,cavab3,cavab4,d_cavab,verilib);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO `vergi_testler`(_id,sual,cavab1,cavab2,cavab3,cavab4,d_cavab,verilib) VALUES (1, 'aaaa', 'aaa1', 'aaa1', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 2, 0);
```

Comment: @NadirNovruzov try by insert keyword and also supply column name ! so try my updated answer !

Answer (score 0):

I found what is the problem. If you want to change something in your database you must do it in onUpgrade() method.